# Tabs with equal (constant) width in JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I'm trying to get a `JTabbedPane` where all tabs (the actual tabs, not the components) have the same width (either the minimum width needed for the widest label or a constant width).

I've tried to override `BasicTabbedPaneUI.getTabBounds(int tabIndex, Rectangle dest)`, but apparently this method isn't used by the painting methods of `BasicTabbedPaneUI`, instead it uses a rects array to determine the tabs size.

My next approach would be to override `JTabbedPane.insertTab(String title, Icon icon, Component component, String tip, int index)` and setting the preferred size of the label component, but this doesn't seem very elegant and I'm not even sure it would work at all.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is simple.
When we put the name for the tab, just format the name using html.
say

tp - JTabbedPane object

```
tp.addTab("<html><body><table width='150'>Name</table></body></html>",Componentobject)
```

Comment: This sounds very good. I've seen other situations where html was the only way to achieve something in swing (e.g. line wrap on tooltips). I'll definitely give it a try.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's not as complicated as you've done. Just use setTabComponentAt() with a JLabel on which you've set preferred size.

Comment: That works, thanks. Unfortunately I have to set all other parameters of the label component (color, font size etc.) myself. I thought of retrieving the label via getTabComponentAt(), but it returns null all the time.

Comment: Yep, that's because the getter only gets a label that was previously set (I think the doco specifically mentions that).

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the following:

```
tabPane.setUI(new javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalTabbedPaneUI() {
    @Override
    protected int calculateTabHeight(int tabPlacement, int tabIndex, int fontHeight) {
        return super.calculateTabHeight(tabPlacement, tabIndex, fontHeight) + 12;
    }
});
```

This seems to work fine for me.  But if your using a different L&F, you'll end up rendering it with the 'metal' regardless.

I guess you could get the default UI and do an 'instanceof' on it to determine which is being used and instantiate it accordingly.

For example:

```
TabbedPaneUI ui = tabPane.getUI();

if (ui instanceof WindowsTabbedPaneUI) {
    // Create the windows rendition
} else if (ui instanceof MetalTabbedPaneUI) {
    // Create the metal rendition
} else if (ui instanceof MotifTabbedPaneUI) {
    // Create the motif rendition
} else if (ui instanceof SynthTabbedPaneUI) {
    // Etc...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is only affecting the tab height, not the width, right?

Comment: @Ole: That's right, I don't know how I came to read width and end up giving  a height example.  Ah well, now there for others who may need it I guess.

Answer (score 1):

this is worked for me.

```
 JLabel lab = new JLabel();
        lab.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
        jTabbedPane1.setTabComponentAt(0, lab);  // tab index, jLabel
```

or try this change to all tab component in same sizes (called in main method)

`UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab.contentMargins", new Insets(10, 100, 0, 0));`