# Adjust tabs in jTabbedpane

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

Im using a jTabbedpane for my application. In normal window size, its like this.

[image]

But when its maximized, Its like this. (Tabs do not change their size).

[image]
I want to adjust tabs as to distribute evenly in any window size.
Thank You.

Comment: *Tabs do not change their size)* thats the expected behavior... Why is it that space needs to be filled so bad?? But anyhow please post and [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @DavidKroukamp Thats space distroys app's neatness. User may change the window size as he wish. so that i don't want the space to be there. suggest me a method please. BTW how to post a SSCCE on a question like this? Thank you.

Comment: The whole point of an SSCCE is to replicate the problem, so we dont have to write the code (and we can see specific problems with your code). As for the tabs spacing, its most likely by coincidence the tabs reach the end of the `JFrame` in fact I think you are calling `setSize(..)` you should be using `pack()` on `JFrame`, as `JTabbedPane` by default does not worry about tab spacing. You could pad the titles with spacing to fill the window via white spaces or better html... see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476678/tabs-with-equal-constant-width-in-jtabbedpane)

Comment: @DavidKroukamp Found the code. Thank you for your helps.

Comment: As a side note the tab Drugs I find really I dont know unfitting .. maybe prescription medicine or something but DRUGS lol :)

Comment: @DavidKroukamp :D we are making a clinical system..so DRUGS= Medicine.. :P

Answer (score 3):

I found a code.

```
        int wid = (tp_main.getSize().width)/6;
        for(int i=0; i<6;i++){
            String name= tp_main.getTitleAt(i);
            tp_main.setTitleAt(i,"<html><div style=\"width: "+new Integer(wid)+"px\">"+new String(name)+"</div></html>");
        }
```

tp_main is the `jTabbedpane`

```
int wid = (tp_main.getSize().width)/6;
```

here devided by 6 as i have 6 tabs.

Comment: FYI: there is no need to instantiate `String` and `Integer` simply use directly `wid` and `name` since they are immutable types.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet here if i used as `"<html><div style=\"width: "+wid+"px\">"+name+"</div></html>" ` ; it compiles the code as `tp_main.setTitleAt(i,"<html><div style=\"width: widpx\">name</div></html>");` It doesn't take it as a Int or String inside a HTML code.

Comment: @Hasi007 I did not say that you have to remove the surrounding quotes and plus (+) sign!, just the wrapping instantiation: `tp_main.setTitleAt(i,"<html><div style=\"width: "+wid+"px\">"+name+"</div></html>");`. Btw, for primitive types, it is always better to go through the `valueOf()` methods: `Integer.valueOf()`, `String.valueOf()`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is when the window size changes, adjust the padding of the tabs dynamically. [Here is a good starting point](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/xuanyun/archive/2009/01/change_the_tab.html).

Comment: Thank you. I tried changing tab sizes. But it fits only for a one window size. Same problem occurs when changing jFrame size.

Answer (score 0):

this is worked for me. change your tab sizes went to remove this space

```
 JLabel lab = new JLabel();
        lab.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
        jTabbedPane1.setTabComponentAt(0, lab);  // tab index, jLabel
```

or try this change to all tab component in same sizes (called in main method)

`UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab.contentMargins", new Insets(10, 100, 0, 0));`